# Different Outputs for a positive and negative value

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

Consider the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
#define SIZE (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int))

int main()
{
        printf("%d",SIZE);
        if(-1<=SIZE) printf("1");
        else printf("2");
        return 0;
}
```

I get 82 as output but if I replace `if(-1<=SIZE)` with `if(0<=SIZE)` or with `if(1<=SIZE)` means -1 in if clause with 0 or non negative number, then I get 81 as output. Why am I getting different outputs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` which is an *unsigned* integer type. When you convert `-1` to an unsigned integer you get a very large number.

Turn on more warnings when building and the compiler will warn you about comparing signed and unsigned data types.

Comment: Shouldn't the comparison coerce both sides to the signed type? I though that was the default.

Comment: Thanx Joachim, this was really pissing me off.

Comment: @Dan: This is _the_ gotcha with mixing unsigned and signed -- which is why many people recommend to always use signed integers if you're going to be doing arithmetic on them and restrict unsigned to bit manipulation (see e.g. http://soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned)